# in tab 2 of front window returns Terminal got an error: Can’t get tab 2 of window 1. (-1728) since High Sierra update

Tags: terminal, applescript, macos-high-sierra

As the title says I have an Apple Script that does:

```
in tab 2 of front window
```

...which used to work fine but since the High Sierra upgrade returns:

```
Terminal got an error: Can’t get tab 2 of window 1. (-1728)
```

Which corresponds to `errAENoSuchObject` I can't find any documentation around this having changed - is this a bug? Is there a new or better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object hierarchy has changed slightly.  Each tab is referenced in AppleScript as *tab 1* belonging to a unique parent *window* object.

So, previously, if there were three tabs open in a single window, we could refer to them as *tab 1*, *tab 2*, and *tab 3* of *window 1*.  Now, we have *tab 1* of *window 1*, *tab 1* of *window 2*, and *tab 1* of *window 3*.

I’ve found the most convenient and reliable way to target a specific tab is to identify the *window* object that contains the *tab* object with a specific **tty** property value.  I use a command that looks something like this:

```
    tell application "Terminal"
        get the id of the first window ¬
            whose first tab's tty contains "003"

        set w to result
        close window id w
    end tell
```

If you want to get a slightly clearer picture of things, run this:

```
    tell application “Terminal” to ¬
        get every tab of every window
```

and this:

```
    tell application “Terminal” to ¬
        get properties of every window
```

and this:

```
    tell application “Terminal” to ¬
        get properties of tab 1 of every window
```

Comment: Nice investigative work! When I posted my now deleted comment about it possibly  being a bug, I hadn't had time to investigate it yet. +1

Comment: Thanks that works! Seems totally bizarre to me though that this would change. Any idea of the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Agreed - bizarre. So you can still write syntax such as "do script "cd api" in tab 3 of front window" but it will never work in High Sierra, as the concept of tab n only exists where n == 1?

Answer (score 4):

If your script's purpose is to open tabs and run a script in each one, and not to navigate between specific tabs, you can easily modify your script to do script `in selected tab of front window` after opening a new tab, as the new tab is always automatically selected. This is my modified script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "YOUR SCRIPT 1" in tab 1 of front window
    my makeTab()
    do script "YOUR SCRIPT 2" in selected tab of front window
    my makeTab()
    do script "YOUR SCRIPT 3" in selected tab of front window
end tell

on makeTab()
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    delay 0.2
end makeTab
```